# c# json parsing format

Tags: javascript, c#, json

In c#, I'm trying to parse JSON that is in the following format. I've only been able to come close using the example code below, but it is very unstable.

(I'm also not sure how to parse in Javascript, which I also need to do.)

JSON example:

```json
{"72": { "Rejected": true }, "271": { "PreApproved": true}}
```

Code example:

```c#
List<SSKChanges> lstSSK = new List<SSKChanges>();
string sskSource = "";
string sskStatus = "";
bool sskStatusBool = false;
int i = 0;
int iList = 0;
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsonExample));
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.Value != null)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            int n;
            bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(reader.Value.ToString(), out n);
            if (isNumeric)
            {
                sskSource = reader.Value.ToString();
                i = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                sskStatus = reader.Value.ToString();
                i = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (i == 1)
        {
            sskStatus = reader.Value.ToString();
            i = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            sskStatusBool = (bool)reader.Value;
            i = 0;
            sskSource = "";
            sskStatus = "";
            sskStatusBool = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you're using Json.Net.  I think you should be looking at the [DeserializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) method.  Also, if you are using Web API or even MVC methods there are other ways of doing this too. Since you didn't specify where you are getting your JSON, I'm assuming it is coming from a file and so you need to deserialize it manually.

Comment: Please be sure to include what your *expected* output is. Refer to this for more: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are already using [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) (as is suggested by your use of [`JsonTextReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm)), you can load your JSON into a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) then [query](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonLinq.htm) the resulting object with [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm).

For instance, given the class:

```
public class SSKChanges
{
    public string SskSource { get; set; }
    public string SskStatus { get; set; }
    public bool? SskStatusBool { get; set; }
}
```

You can do:

```
        var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonExample);
        var lstSSK = (from property in obj.Properties()
                      select new SSKChanges
                      {
                          SskSource = property.Name,
                          SskStatus = property.Value.Children<JProperty>().Select(p2 => p2.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                          SskStatusBool = property.Value.Children<JProperty>().Select(p2 => (bool?)p2.Value).FirstOrDefault()
                      }).ToList();
```

As for the second question in your question, *i'm also not sure how to parse in javascript, I need to do that too*, you should ask a second question directed specifically at javascript experts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using Json.net, I would do it as:

```
string json = @"{""72"": { ""Rejected"": true }, ""271"": { ""PreApproved"": true}}";
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (var entry in jobj.Children().Cast<JProperty>())
{
    var kv = entry.Value.First() as JProperty;
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Name + "=>" + kv.Name + ":"  + kv.Value);
}
```